# Flexbox box-shadow webkit

Tags: html, css

I've tried to add box-shadow on my navbar and it seems like content covers it up.

```css
.value,
.icon,
.text,
.date {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.current {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 height: 50px;
 background: grey;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #000;
    /* z-index doesn't help here */
    z-index: 9999;
}

.current h1 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.items {
 min-height: 50px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
 height: 50px;
 background: #eee;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
 display: flex;
}

.icon {
 width: 30px;
 min-width: 30px;
 justify-content: center;
 
}

.up {
 background: #F1F8E9;
}

.down {
 background: #FFEBEE;
}

.up > .icon {
 background: #8BC34A;
}

.down > .icon {
 background: #F44336;
}

.icon > span {
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 align-self: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.value > span {
 align-self: center;
 font: 700 24px/24px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.up > .value > span {
 color: #8BC34A;
}

.down > .value > span {
 color: #F44336;
}

.text {
 height: 50px;
}

.date {
 margin-left: auto;
}

.text > span {
 font: 500 16px/16px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

.date > span {
 display: flex;
 font: 600 12px/12px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
 height: 15px;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="current" class="current">
  <h1 id="pocket">Box-shadow</h1>
</div>
<div id="items" class="items">
  <div class="item up">
    <div class="icon">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>250</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>First message</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <span>20.09.2016</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item down">
    <div class="icon">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>250</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>Second message</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <span>20.09.2016</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried `z-index` property on my `.current` element but it didn't help. Is there a mistake in my code or should I use a certain property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `z-index` to work you need positioning, so add `position: relative;` to your `.current`

```css
.value,
.icon,
.text,
.date {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.current {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 height: 50px;
 background: grey;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 6px #000;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.current h1 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.items {
 min-height: 50px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
 height: 50px;
 background: #eee;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
 display: flex;
}

.icon {
 width: 30px;
 min-width: 30px;
 justify-content: center;
 
}

.up {
 background: #F1F8E9;
}

.down {
 background: #FFEBEE;
}

.up > .icon {
 background: #8BC34A;
}

.down > .icon {
 background: #F44336;
}

.icon > span {
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 align-self: center;
 color: #fff;
}

.value > span {
 align-self: center;
 font: 700 24px/24px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.up > .value > span {
 color: #8BC34A;
}

.down > .value > span {
 color: #F44336;
}

.text {
 height: 50px;
}

.date {
 margin-left: auto;
}

.text > span {
 font: 500 16px/16px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 10px 0 0 5px;
}

.date > span {
 display: flex;
 font: 600 12px/12px "Roboto", sans-serif;
 padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
 height: 15px;
 align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="current" class="current">
  <h1 id="pocket">Box-shadow</h1>
</div>
<div id="items" class="items">
  <div class="item up">
    <div class="icon">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>250</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>First message</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <span>20.09.2016</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item down">
    <div class="icon">
      <span class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <span>250</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <span>Second message</span>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
      <span>20.09.2016</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```